# how to fix "Failed to request MethodData, not in JIT code range" error

Tags: .net, wcf, debugging, clr, windbg

```
0:000> g
TTD: End of trace reached.
(1fe4.59dc): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first/second chance not available)
Time Travel Position: 33D60F:0
clr!MetaData::TableRO::GetRecord+0x3:
00007ffb`97c3b863 48895808        mov     qword ptr [rax+8],rbx ds:00000000`0014bc70=000000003530bb58
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
0:000> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 00000000`0014bc68 00007ffb`97c46dfd clr!MetaData::TableRO::GetRecord+0x3
01 00000000`0014bc70 00007ffb`97d6b79b clr!MDInternalRO::GetParentToken+0xe9
02 00000000`0014bce0 00007ffb`96adefee clr!MetaDataImport::GetParentToken+0x6b
03 00000000`0014bd50 00007ffb`96a35ff9 mscorlib_ni+0x54efee
04 00000000`0014be40 00007ffb`96a55783 mscorlib_ni+0x4a5ff9
05 00000000`0014bf80 00007ffb`6fc27192 mscorlib_ni+0x4c5783
06 00000000`0014bfd0 00007ffb`6fc269a2 System_ServiceModel_ni+0x5d7192
07 00000000`0014c010 00007ffb`6fc221eb System_ServiceModel_ni+0x5d69a2
08 00000000`0014c0c0 00007ffb`6fc21fa6 System_ServiceModel_ni+0x5d21eb
09 00000000`0014c150 00007ffb`6fb9b15d System_ServiceModel_ni+0x5d1fa6
0a 00000000`0014c190 00007ffb`6fc0ae5d System_ServiceModel_ni+0x54b15d
0b 00000000`0014c1d0 00007ffb`7054a2fe System_ServiceModel_ni+0x5bae5d
0c 00000000`0014c240 00007ffb`38c4cbae System_ServiceModel_ni+0xefa2fe
0d 00000000`0014c2b0 00000000`358ba898 0x00007ffb`38c4cbae
0e 00000000`0014c2b8 00000000`358ba9f0 0x358ba898
0f 00000000`0014c2c0 00000000`00000000 0x358ba9f0
```

Here's the stack including mangaed and unmanged frames:

```
0:000> !mk
Thread 0:
           SP               IP
00:U 000000000014bc68 00007ffb97c3b863 clr!MetaData::TableRO::GetRecord+0x3
01:U 000000000014bc70 00007ffb97c46dfd clr!MDInternalRO::GetParentToken+0xe9
02:U 000000000014bce0 00007ffb97d6b79b clr!MetaDataImport::GetParentToken+0x6b
03:M 000000000014bd50 00007ffb96adefee System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(System.Reflection.CustomAttributeRecord, System.Reflection.MetadataImport, System.Reflection.Assembly ByRef, System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, System.Reflection.MetadataToken, System.RuntimeType(+0x36 IL,+0x7e Native)
04:M 000000000014be40 00007ffb96a35ff9 System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsCustomAttributeDefined(System.Reflection.RuntimeModule, Int32, System.RuntimeType, Int32, Boolean)(+0x3d IL,+0x149 Native)
05:M 000000000014bf80 00007ffb96a55783 System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(System.RuntimeType, System.RuntimeType, Boolean)(+0x10 IL,+0x73 Native)
06:M 000000000014bfd0 00007ffb6fc27192 System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.GetFormattingAttribute(System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider, System.Attribute)(+0x3 IL,+0x32 Native)
07:M 000000000014c010 00007ffb6fc269a2 System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.AddBehaviors(System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription, System.Type, Boolean, ContractReflectionInfo)(+0x206 IL,+0x3f2 Native)
08:M 000000000014c0c0 00007ffb6fc221eb System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.LoadContractDescriptionHelper(System.Type, System.Type, System.Object)(+0xfc IL,+0x13b Native)
[WARNING: Multiple managed methods at this address]09:M 000000000014c150 00007ffb6fc21fa6 System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].CreateDescription()(+0x0 IL,+0x56 Native)
0a:M 000000000014c190 00007ffb6fb9b15d System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress)(+0x0 IL,+0x1d Native)
[WARNING: Multiple managed methods at this address]0b:M 000000000014c1d0 00007ffb6fc0ae5d System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress)(+0x63 IL,+0x9d Native)
[WARNING: Multiple managed methods at this address]0c:M 000000000014c240 00007ffb7054a2fe System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress)(+0x7a IL,+0x13e Native)
0d:M 000000000014c2b0 00007ffb38c4cbae CNCClient.CNCService.CNCServiceClient.SetupNetTcpEndpoint()(+0x5c IL,+0xfe Native)
0e:U 000000000014c2b8 00000000358ba898 CLRStub@00000000358ba898
0f:U 000000000014c2c0 00000000358ba9f0 CLRStub@00000000358ba9f0
10:M 000000000014f070 00007ffb386d3288 DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke()
11:U 000000000014f120 00007ffb97c16793 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
12:U 000000000014f160 00007ffb97c16665 clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4e
13:U 000000000014f1a0 00007ffb97c1736d clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0xf8
14:U 000000000014f2a0 00007ffb97d138b7 clr!RunMain+0x1ee
15:U 000000000014f480 00007ffb97d140fa clr!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod+0xb6
16:U 000000000014f770 00007ffb97d13fb7 clr!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod+0x639
17:U 000000000014fd90 00007ffb97d1394d clr!ExecuteEXE+0x3f
18:U 000000000014fe00 00007ffb97d13732 clr!_CorExeMainInternal+0xb2
19:U 000000000014fe90 00007ffb97d146a4 clr!CorExeMain+0x14
1a:U 000000000014fed0 00007ffbb1e7a56d mscoreei!CorExeMain+0x112
1b:U 000000000014ff30 00007ffbb2b8a44c MSCOREE!CorExeMain_Exported+0x6c
1c:U 000000000014ff60 00007ffbcd102774 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
1d:U 000000000014ff90 00007ffbcfb30d51 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

Here's the output from analyze:

```
0:000> !analyze -v

*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DBGHELP: C:\WINDOWS\system32\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll - file not found
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x26D
         https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
         599668C7179e000
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x26E
         https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
         599668C7179e000
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: C:\WINDOWS\system32\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll - file not found
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x26F
         https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
         599668C7179e000
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x270
         https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
         599668C7179e000
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
DBGHELP: C:\WINDOWS\system32\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll - file not found
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x271
         https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
         599668C7179e000
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x272
         https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
         599668C7179e000
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  UNC:    C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_ - path not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll\599668C7179e000\file.ptr - path not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/System.ServiceModel.ni.dl_
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/System.ServiceModel.ni.dll/599668C7179e000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 80190194 - HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x80190194

MethodDesc:   00007ffb38cacb08
Method Name:  CNCClient.CNCService.CNCServiceClient.SetupNetTcpEndpoint()
Class:        00007ffb38cf4978
MethodTable:  00007ffb38cadc18
mdToken:      0000000006000003
Module:       00007ffb38cab2f8
IsJitted:     yes
CodeAddr:     00007ffb38c4cab0
Transparency: Critical
Failed to request MethodData, not in JIT code range
Failed to request MethodData, not in JIT code range
GetUrlPageData2 (WinHttp) failed: 12002.

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1

Timeline: !analyze.Start
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2017-12-25T15:41:04.555Z
    Diff: 3624555 mSec

Timeline: Dump.Current
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2017-12-25T14:40:40.0Z
    Diff: 0 mSec

Timeline: OS.Boot
    Name: <blank>
    Time: 2017-12-20T15:06:01.0Z
    Diff: 430479000 mSec


DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 2

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
00000000`00000000 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

FAULTING_THREAD:  000059dc

BUGCHECK_STR:  BREAKPOINT

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT

PROCESS_NAME:  PCDLRN.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint  A breakpoint has been reached.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - One or more arguments are invalid

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80000003

WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP:  5a3ed36a

WATSON_BKT_PROCVER:  2018.1.0.0

PROCESS_VER_PRODUCT:  Hexagon Manufacturing Intelligence

WATSON_BKT_MODULE:  unknown

WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  0.0.0.0

WATSON_BKT_MODOFFSET:  0

WATSON_BKT_MODSTAMP:  bbbbbbb4

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.15063.296 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

MODLIST_WITH_TSCHKSUM_HASH:  5602b8cf2cb6854628c599b69cf1150c65cec3d5

MODLIST_SHA1_HASH:  ac61a4c7dcbf5fd177a48071062fd4df2ed2cd86

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

PROCESS_BAM_CURRENT_THROTTLED: 0

PROCESS_BAM_PREVIOUS_THROTTLED: 0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

SUITE_MASK:  272

DUMP_TYPE:  fe

MISSING_CLR_SYMBOL: 0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  USWAI-PC-01257

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  12-25-2017 10:41:04.0555

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.17061.1000 amd64fre

MANAGED_CODE: 1

MANAGED_ENGINE_MODULE:  clr

MANAGED_ANALYSIS_PROVIDER:  SOS

MANAGED_THREAD_ID: 59dc

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
OS_LOCALE:  ENU

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 

    ID:     [0n316]
    Type:   [@APPLICATION_FAULT_STRING]
    Class:  Primary
    Scope:  DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID (Failure Bucket ID prefix)
            BUCKET_ID
    Name:   Omit
    Data:   Add
            String: [BREAKPOINT]
    PID:    [Unspecified]
    TID:    [Unspecified]
    Frame:  [0]

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  BREAKPOINT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 00007ffb97c46dfd to 00007ffb97c3b863

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`0014bc68 00007ffb`97c46dfd : 00000000`3530bb58 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`3530baa8 : clr!MetaData::TableRO::GetRecord+0x3
00000000`0014bc70 00007ffb`97d6b79b : 00007ffb`97dbe860 00000000`60125620 00000000`0014bdd8 00007ffb`96adcde7 : clr!MDInternalRO::GetParentToken+0xe9
00000000`0014bce0 00007ffb`96adefee : 00000000`3530baa8 00000000`0014be30 00000000`0014bea8 00000000`0014bf18 : clr!MetaDataImport::GetParentToken+0x6b
00000000`0014bd50 00007ffb`96a35ff9 : 00000000`3599fee8 00007ffb`96adcfe7 00000000`00000000 00007ffb`97d61660 : mscorlib_ni+0x54efee
00000000`0014be40 00007ffb`96a55783 : 00000000`00000000 00007ffb`96a556e4 00000000`359ab090 00000000`00000003 : mscorlib_ni+0x4a5ff9
00000000`0014bf80 00007ffb`6fc27192 : 00000000`3596da68 00007ffb`6fc26fe3 00000000`3596da68 00000000`359ab090 : mscorlib_ni+0x4c5783
00000000`0014bfd0 00007ffb`6fc269a2 : 00007ffb`6fd0e2f0 00000000`35946260 00000000`358bb070 00000000`352fd0a0 : System_ServiceModel_ni+0x5d7192
00000000`0014c010 00007ffb`6fc221eb : 00000000`358bace8 00000000`358bb070 00000000`358bb008 00000000`00000000 : System_ServiceModel_ni+0x5d69a2
00000000`0014c0c0 00007ffb`6fc21fa6 : 00000000`358bace8 00007ffb`96adcfe7 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`fffffffe : System_ServiceModel_ni+0x5d21eb
00000000`0014c150 00007ffb`6fb9b15d : 00000000`358ba7c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`ffffffff 00000000`358baa38 : System_ServiceModel_ni+0x5d1fa6
00000000`0014c190 00007ffb`6fc0ae5d : 00000000`00000004 00007ffb`6fc219c4 00000000`358ba558 00007ffb`6fc05f97 : System_ServiceModel_ni+0x54b15d
00000000`0014c1d0 00007ffb`7054a2fe : 00000000`358bab38 00000000`358baac8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : System_ServiceModel_ni+0x5bae5d
00000000`0014c240 00007ffb`38c4cbae : 00000000`358ba898 00000000`358ba9f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : System_ServiceModel_ni+0xefa2fe
00000000`0014c2b0 00000000`358ba898 : 00000000`358ba9f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`0014c330 : 0x00007ffb`38c4cbae
00000000`0014c2b8 00000000`358ba9f0 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`0014c330 00000000`00000000 : 0x358ba898
00000000`0014c2c0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`0014c330 00000000`00000000 00000000`0014c330 : 0x358ba9f0


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s ; .cxr ; kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  bb948af0a3aaf86129d8c0d636862431919761c0

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  b1602b8475f8387645d7dfd7bbc542006e3154ba

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  4062ddbf0d03216c40275dec5ecb06c839e4cfcd

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
clr!MetaData::TableRO::GetRecord+3
00007ffb`97c3b863 48895808        mov     qword ptr [rax+8],rbx

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  8588948

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  clr!MetaData::TableRO::GetRecord+3

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: clr

IMAGE_NAME:  clr.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  59af8ce5

BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_clr!MetaData::TableRO::GetRecord+3

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  80000003

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  clr.dll

BUCKET_ID_IMAGE_STR:  clr.dll

FAILURE_MODULE_NAME:  clr

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  clr

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  MetaData::TableRO::GetRecord

BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR:  MetaData::TableRO::GetRecord

BUCKET_ID_OFFSET:  3

BUCKET_ID_MODPRIVATE: 1

BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP:  59af8ce5

BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM:  9dd510

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  4.7.2115.0

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  BREAKPOINT_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  BREAKPOINT

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  clr.dll!MetaData::TableRO::GetRecord

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_80000003_clr.dll!MetaData::TableRO::GetRecord

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/PCDLRN.exe/2018.1.0.0/5a3ed36a/unknown/0.0.0.0/bbbbbbb4/80000003/00000000.htm?Retriage=1

TARGET_TIME:  2017-12-25T14:40:40.000Z

OSBUILD:  15063

OSSERVICEPACK:  296

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  unknown_date

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  160101.0800

BUILDLAB_STR:  WinBuild

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.15063.296

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  7624

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:breakpoint_80000003_clr.dll!metadata::tablero::getrecord

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {124f381b-9820-6ee7-34f2-cf9f57cd1393}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Does anything look obvious here? If not, what would be the next steps to detect this unexpected application close? Unfortunately, neither procdump or VS debugger yielded any clues so I am left to try windbg but I am a novice here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you very much.

EDIT 1. This executable is a C++ application which links to some C++/CLI projects. It communicates via WCF to another C# application which hosts the service.

EDIT 2. Here's some additional information on frame 0 of the stack:

```
0:000> !mframe 0
0:000> !mdso
Thread 0:
Location          Object            Type
------------------------------------------------------------
000000000014bc70  000000003530bb58  System.RuntimeType
000000000014bc88  000000003530baa8  System.Reflection.RuntimeModule
000000000014bdf8  00000000353feb68  System.RuntimeType
000000000014be10  00000000359ab210  System.Reflection.CustomAttributeRecord[]
000000000014be40  000000003599fee8  System.CodeDom.CodeNamespaceCollection
000000000014bf40  00000000352fd0a0  System.RuntimeType
000000000014bf50  00000000359ab120  System.Collections.ArrayList
000000000014bf68  0000000035311e98  System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo
000000000014bf90  00000000359ab090  System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationGenerator
000000000014bfa8  000000003596ee88  System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription
000000000014bfc0  00000000353fec30  System.ServiceModel.DataContractFormatAttribute
000000000014bfd0  000000003596da68  System.Collections.Generic.KeyedByTypeCollection`1[[System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior, System.ServiceModel]]
000000000014bff8  00000000358bb070  System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription
000000000014c018  0000000035946260  System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription
000000000014c058  00000000353141d8  System.RuntimeType
000000000014c068  00000000358bb280  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Type, mscorlib]]
000000000014c078  00000000358baa38  System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress
000000000014c098  00000000358bab38  System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[[CNCClient.CNCService.ICNCService, CNCClient]]
000000000014c0c0  00000000358bace8  System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader
000000000014c0d0  00000000358bb008  System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader+ContractReflectionInfo
000000000014c100  00000000358bad10  System.Object
000000000014c120  00000000358baeb0  System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute
000000000014c140  000000000014c230  CNCClient.CNCService.CNCServiceClient
000000000014c180  00000000358ba558  System.ServiceModel.NetTcpBinding
000000000014c190  00000000358ba7c0  System.Uri
000000000014c1f8  00000000358baac8  CNCClient.CNCService.CNCServiceClient
000000000014c228  00007ffb38cae458  CNCClient.CNCService.ICNCService
000000000014c270  00000000358ba898  System.ServiceModel.DnsEndpointIdentity
000000000014c298  00000000352f77f8  System.String  "CNCService"
000000000014c2b8  00000000358ba9f0  System.IdentityModel.Claims.Claim
000000000014c300  00000000358ba388  System.String  "Starting client connection to CNCService... "
000000000014c4b0  00000000352f6608  System.RuntimeMethodInfoStub
000000000014cba0  00000000352f5510  System.WeakReference
000000000014cc98  00000000352f51a8  System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly
000000000014ce68  0000000035114c90  System.Windows.Baml2006.WpfSharedBamlSchemaContext
000000000014cea0  0000000035114e98  System.Xaml.XamlSchemaContext+WeakReferenceList`1[[System.Reflection.Assembly, mscorlib]]
000000000014cef0  00000000350d3fe8  System.Text.StringBuilder
000000000014cf80  00000000352f51e0  **** FREE ****
000000000014cfa0  00000000350f76e0  MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourceContainer
000000000014cfb0  00000000350f2a88  System.Globalization.TextInfo
000000000014cfb8  00000000352f53c0  System.String  "CNCClientWrapper"
000000000014cfd0  0000000035114da8  System.Object
000000000014cfe0  00000000350d1550  System.AppDomain
000000000014d1f8  000000000014d3e0  
000000000014d348  000000000014d3b8  
000000000014fa18  00000000350d1440  System.SharedStatics
```

Comment: Nothing to debug, this is a "should never happen" mishap.  The machine that produced this trace is not reliable anymore.  Replacing the RAM modules might salvage it but nuke from orbit is the only way to be sure.

Comment: @HansPassant What leads you to this conclusion? We are seeing the same application behavior on multiple machines.

Comment: It looks like the CLR metadata is destroyed. Are you doing some native interop stuff? Maybe some C++ wrote to regions of memory where it shouldn't

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, my project uses C++ Interop to connect to a WCF service hosted in a different C# application. Any idea how I can track down what lines are overwriting the memory?